# Safari shows an error when IPB redirects it to an https:// URL with language accents

Tags: ssl, nginx, utf-8, https, safari

My https switch is almost complete. Everything works flawlessly on every browser **except Safari** (both iOS and OSX).

Some URLs contain Polish characters, such as żźćąłóń. Apparently in some cases Invision Power Board encodes them, so for example `ó` becomes `%F3`.

#### Example 1

- HTTP version works: `http://net4game.com/topic/256549-rekrutujemy-gamemaster%F3w/`
- HTTPS with a special UTF8 character works as well: `https://net4game.com/topic/256549-rekrutujemy-gamemasterów/`
- Does **not** work when `ó` is encoded: https://net4game.com/topic/256549-rekrutujemy-gamemaster%F3w/

  ```
  [29/Aug/2015:17:19:56 +0200] "GET /topic/256549-rekrutujemy-gamemaster%F3w/ HTTP/1.1" 301 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.8 Safari/600.8.9"
  ```

#### Example 2

- HTTP works: `http://net4game.com/topic/256786-bug-ślub/`
- HTTPS works: `https://net4game.com/topic/256786-bug-ślub/`
- HTTPS, UTF8, with a **redirect**, does not work: [https://net4game.com/topic/256786-bug-ślub/?view=getlastpost](https://net4game.com/topic/256786-bug-%C5%9Blub/?view=getlastpost)

I'm using **nginx** behind CloudFlare. Every request goes to **index.php**.

What could be wrong? Why does this problem occur only on HTTPS? It seems Safari doesn't rewrite `%F3` to `ó` over encrypted connections, but I'm not sure it's relevant, as the second example seems to stick to the unencoded `ś`.

Cheers.

Comment: For https://net4game.com/topic/256549-rekrutujemy-gamemaster%F3w/ I get a `Too many redirects` redirect-loop warning. But I can’t reproduce it in any other browser or tool (including `wget` or `curl`). They all redirect to https://net4game.com/topic/256549-rekrutujemy-gamemasterów/ as expected. Same for https://net4game.com/topic/256786-bug-ślub/#entry2836978. It redirects to https://net4game.com/topic/256786-bug-ślub/#entry2836978 as expected, except in Safari. But for that one I don’t get the "Too many redirects" redirect-loop warning; instead I just get a “This Page Can’t Be Found” message.